# Shared resource on Kotlin Multiplatform with cocoapods not found on iOS

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to use the example https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform-template and Voyger tab navigation

one of tabs include images from "commonMain/resources"

```
    @OptIn(ExperimentalResourceApi::class)
    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        Column(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(MaterialTheme.colors.background)
        ) {

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
            Image(
                painter = painterResource("ic_logo.xml"),
                contentDescription = "",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(600.dp)
                    .weight(1f)
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
            Image(
                painter = painterResource("ic_big_image.png"),
                contentDescription = "",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .weight(5f),
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight
            )
        }
    }
```

My shared module build.kts is

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose")
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget()

    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach { iosTarget ->
        iosTarget.binaries.framework {
            binaryOption("bundleId", "com.myapp.myapp")
            binaryOption("bundleVersion", "2")
            baseName = "shared"
            isStatic = true
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(compose.runtime)
                implementation(compose.foundation)
                implementation(compose.material)
                @OptIn(org.jetbrains.compose.ExperimentalComposeLibrary::class)
                implementation(compose.components.resources)
                api("io.github.kevinnzou:compose-webview-multiplatform:1.5.0")
                val voyagerVersion = "1.0.0-rc05"
                implementation("cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:$voyagerVersion")
                implementation("cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-tab-navigator:$voyagerVersion")

            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                api("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.0")
                api("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
                api("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
            }
        }
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk = (findProperty("android.compileSdk") as String).toInt()
    namespace = "com.myapp.common"

    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    sourceSets["main"].res.srcDirs("src/androidMain/res")
    sourceSets["main"].resources.srcDirs("src/commonMain/resources")

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = (findProperty("android.minSdk") as String).toInt()
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(17)
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation("com.android.car.ui:car-ui-lib:2.5.1")
}
```

All works fine. But if I add cocoapods, then when I go to this tab the program crashes

```
Uncaught Kotlin exception: org.jetbrains.compose.resources.MissingResourceException: Missing resource with path: ic_autodealer_logo.xml
```

My new build.kts with cocoapods

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
}

@OptIn(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
kotlin {
    androidTarget()

    iosX64()
    iosArm64()
    iosSimulatorArm64()

    cocoapods {
        summary = "Some description for the Shared Module"
        homepage = "Link to the Shared Module homepage"
        version = "1.0"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "14.2"
        framework {
            baseName = "shared"
            isStatic = true
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(compose.runtime)
                implementation(compose.foundation)
                implementation(compose.material)
                @OptIn(org.jetbrains.compose.ExperimentalComposeLibrary::class)
                implementation(compose.components.resources)
                api("io.github.kevinnzou:compose-webview-multiplatform:1.5.0")
                val voyagerVersion = "1.0.0-rc05"
                implementation("cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:$voyagerVersion")
                implementation("cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-tab-navigator:$voyagerVersion")

            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                api("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.0")
                api("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
                api("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
            }
        }
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk = (findProperty("android.compileSdk") as String).toInt()
    namespace = "com.myapp.common"

    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    sourceSets["main"].res.srcDirs("src/androidMain/res")
    sourceSets["main"].resources.srcDirs("src/commonMain/resources")

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = (findProperty("android.minSdk") as String).toInt()
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(17)
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation("com.android.car.ui:car-ui-lib:2.5.1")
}
```

shared.podspec

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
    spec.name                     = 'shared'
    spec.version                  = '1.0'
    spec.homepage                 = 'Link to the Shared Module homepage'
    spec.source                   = { :http=> ''}
    spec.authors                  = ''
    spec.license                  = ''
    spec.summary                  = 'Some description for the Shared Module'
    spec.vendored_frameworks      = 'build/cocoapods/framework/shared.framework'
    spec.libraries                = 'c++'
    spec.ios.deployment_target = '14.2'
                
                
    spec.pod_target_xcconfig = {
        'KOTLIN_PROJECT_PATH' => ':shared',
        'PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME' => 'shared',
    }
                
    spec.script_phases = [
        {
            :name => 'Build shared',
            :execution_position => :before_compile,
            :shell_path => '/bin/sh',
            :script => <<-SCRIPT
                if [ "YES" = "$OVERRIDE_KOTLIN_BUILD_IDE_SUPPORTED" ]; then
                  echo "Skipping Gradle build task invocation due to OVERRIDE_KOTLIN_BUILD_IDE_SUPPORTED environment variable set to \"YES\""
                  exit 0
                fi
                set -ev
                REPO_ROOT="$PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT"
                "$REPO_ROOT/../gradlew" -p "$REPO_ROOT" $KOTLIN_PROJECT_PATH:syncFramework \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.platform=$PLATFORM_NAME \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.archs="$ARCHS" \
                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.configuration="$CONFIGURATION"
            SCRIPT
        }
    ]
    spec.resources = ['build/compose/ios/shared/resources']
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these steps to resolve the issue:

1. Run `./gradlew clean` or delete `build` folder
2. Run `pod install` in the iOS project.
3. Verify the contents of the `compose/ios/${framework.baseName}/compose-resources/` build folder to ensure it contains all the necessary resources.

Also Compose Multiplatform's resources management for iOS is experimental library, you can try more stable alternatives: [Moko Resources](https://github.com/icerockdev/moko-resources) or [Libres](https://github.com/Skeptick/libres).

Comment: Thanks, I think about Moko. But why it works fine before cocoapods add?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, you are right, JetBrains Compose has experimental resource management tool and you use it, I missed it. And it seems it should work

Comment: Hm. My "compose-resourse" locate in 'compose/ios/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/compose-resources/'  .

Comment: try run `gradle clean` or delete `build` directory. Probably Gradle cached sync resources task, since resources haven't changed